# Batch Georectifying Imagery

Tags: python, gdal, georeferencing

I have a large collection of drone images that aren't georeferenced. I'd like to georectify them by pulling projection and coordinate data from the GeoTiff files, but I'm having difficulty.

My initial thought is to use GDAL in Python to pull lat/long data and use that to georectify the images, but I don't have much experience with GDAL or georectification through scripting.

Any advice to help me get started?

Comment: You might want to look at the OpenDroneMap project http://opendronemap.github.io/odm/